# CNContactViewController navigation bar colour not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, contacts, cncontactviewcontroller

CNContactViewController navigation bar colour not appearing when i click **Create New Contact** option. See my screens for 1st time it's ok, but when i click **Create New Contact** i'm not getting navigation bar colour and not visible back button.

1st screen

[image]

2nd screen

[image]

In older versions

[image]

My code is

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue : self.mobile ?? ""))
        contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]
        let controller = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact : contact)
        controller.contactStore = store
        controller.delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: {
                //Set status bar background colour
                let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
                statusBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                //Set navigation bar subView background colour
                for view in controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
                    view.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }
            })
        }

        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
```

And one more is by default phone number: **(913) 351-5518**

Comment: Are you using default navigation bar or custom? Custom means with UIView background colour and custom back button.

Comment: To achieve this I'm using custom navigation View see this. for view in controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {

Comment: @shahnilay86, because of in iOS 10 onwards CNContactViewController navigation bar not showing by default.

Comment: @shahnilay86, this problem occurs only from iOS 10 onwards . In iOS 9.0 it's working properly.

Comment: Have you give appropriate constraint to Navigation bar? Like Height..

Comment: @ shahnilay86, see this code , I'm not mentioned frame here. Directly I assigned to subViews.  //Set navigation bar subView background colour
                for view in controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {
                    view.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to display a CNConctactViewController within a UINavigationController in Popover Modal Presentation style, and add a few button to return to the main application. This implementation seams not trivial as reported by rumours over the net.

Let me share a few pieces of my code (swift 5).

The major class:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

   var contactViewController = CNContactViewController()
   ...
   @objc func dismissContactViewController() {
      contactViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

The extension:

```
extension MyViewController: CNContactViewControllerDelegate {

func openCNContactViewController(willAppearWith: CNContact, type: ContactType) {
    switch type {
    case .forContact:
        contactViewController = CNContactViewController(for: willAppearWith)
        contactViewController.allowsEditing = false
        break
    case .forNewContact:
        contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: willAppearWith)
        contactViewController.allowsEditing = true
        break
    case .forUnknowContact:
        contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: willAppearWith)
        contactViewController.allowsEditing = true
        break
    }
    contactViewController.allowsActions = true
    contactViewController.contactStore = globalContactStore
    contactViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    contactViewController.delegate = self
    // define the button (or select a default one)
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("My app name", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissContactViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
    let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    closeButton.style = .plain

    // add flexible space
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    // add to toolbar
    contactViewController.setToolbarItems([flexibleSpace, closeButton, flexibleSpace], animated: false)

    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)

    // show toolbar
    navigationVC.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)

    // set navigation presentation style
    navigationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    // present view controller
    self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

The result
[image]